# Creating a line break in html

Tags: html, vba, outlook

**Scenario:** I am trying to meddle with the output of an email that is going to be sent with VBA. I am trying to add a background image and a piece of text.

**Issue:** The image part is working properly, but I am not being able to get the text to be divided in 3 lines.

**Obs:** I never used HTML in my life, but apparently it is the only way to change the background of my email with VBA. I tried looking for an answer online, but the best I got was to use `<br>` which is not working for me.

**Question:** What is the proper way to do this?

**Code:**

```
Private Sub mailer2()
Dim oApp, oMail As Object, MyHTML As String, WB As Workbook, FileName As String, BodyText As String, MyText As String, MyText2 As String, MyText3 As String
Dim username As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)

    username = InputBox("Please write your E-mail")

    MyText = "Greetings"
    MyText2 = "Your Macro.V.0.4 has concluded."
    MyText = "Please attend to terminal AFAP"


    MyHTML = vbCrLf & "<p style=""font-size:18px;font-weight:Bold;color:rgb(100,100,100)"">" & MyText1 & "<br>" & MyText2 & "<br>" & MyText3 & "</p>"

    'this next works, but puts everything into a single line
    'MyHTML = MyHTML & vbCrLf & "<p style=""font-size:19px;font-weight:Bold;color:rgb(100,100,100)"">" & MyText & "</p>"

    With oMail
        .To = username
        .Subject = "Automated message, please do not answer"
        .HTMLBody = MyHTML
        .Send
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set oMail = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Unsure if this will work as the double double quotes maybe causing an issue... but try using character codes instead of double quotes:... MyHTML = vbCrLf & "<p style=" & Chr(34) & "font-size:18px;font-weight:Bold;color:rgb(100,100,100)" & Chr(34) & ">" & MyText1 & "<br>" & MyText2 & "<br>" & MyText3 & "</p>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the HTML for a line break:

```
<br>
```

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in the OP, I found that <br> generates a line break, and I used it in my code. But it does not work in the way I am using it.

Comment: I dont see why not... Add `Debug.Print MyHTML` and double check your immediate window to ensure you are getting what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, I did that, and the output is just the variable MyText2 instead of the combination of them

Comment: Ah, I found the error, it was in the variables that I send to HTML.

Comment: Should this be `MyText3`?  `MyText = "Please attend to terminal AFAP"`

Comment: Precisely, I just saw that, total stupidity of mine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Other than what brax said (`<br>`) you can use the horizontal rule tag `<hr>`.
Put any one of those between the texts you want to divide.

EDIT: try removing " " of your html. tags are used without those.

EDIT2: Nevermind my first edit, i misread your code. Try `<br><br>`. It should work.

In general, your question was a pretty basic one. Next time try to dig some more before making a post. It's easy to answer questions like this.

Comment: Yes I understand this is basic. My research led me to <br>, as I said, and I used it in my code. But even with that it is not working in the expected  way, and I can quite figure out why.

Comment: I edited my answer, give it a try without quotations